pytest: Mocked value is not returned
My code is the following:
def get_inspection_details(insp_id: int) -> dict:
    db = get_session()

    inspection_details = (
        db.query(
           # some fields here
        )
        .filter(dbm.Inspection.id == insp_id)
        .first()
    )

    return inspection_details._asdict()

@pytest.fixture(name="mock_flask_db_session", scope="function")
def mock_flask_db_session(mocker: pytest_mock.MockerFixture,
                          test_app_context: AppContext) -> Generator[pytest_mock.MockFixture, None, None]:
    # Mock the get_session method
    mock_inspection_get_session = mocker.patch("package_a", autospec=True)
    
    # Create a mock session object
    mock_session = MagicMock(spec=sa.orm.scoped_session)
    mock_inspection_get_session.return_value = mock_session
    with test_app_context:
        yield mock_session

    # Optionally, reset the mock after the test
    mock_session.reset_mock(return_value=True, side_effect=True)

def mock_inspection(mock_db) -> None:
    mock_db.return_value.query.return_value.filter.return_value.first.return_value = inspection
    
def test_get_mq_image(mock_flask_db_session: mock.Mock,
                      test_app_context: AppContext):
    mock_inspection(mock_flask_db_session)
    details = inspection_utils.get_inspection_details(insp_id=1)
    print(details)

I am mocking a database session - mock_flask_db_session - which I inject into the mock_inspection method to mock a return value. The method under test is get_inspection_details.
My problem is that db.query does not return the Inspection that I am configuring it to return. Instead it returns <MagicMock name='mock.query().filter().first()' id='14676603856'>.
I have tried mocking the return_value with
mock_db.return_value.query.return_value.filter.side_effect = [inspection]
mock_db.return_value.query.return_value.filter.side_effect.first.return_value = inspection

but the mocking breaks before the test runs. What is the issue here?
